# ¿Cómo usar la API de Google Adsense usando PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-adsense

Estoy usando la api de [google adense](https://developers.google.com/adsense/) y, en su documentación completa:

- https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/get
- https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/direct_requests

He instalado las bibliotecas requeridas usando composer, he usado los dos métodos de uso:

```
composer require google/apiclient:"^2.7"
```

Y, descargando el proyecto:

```
google-api-php-client-[RELEASE_NAME].zip
```

Teniendo las siguientes carpetas:

```
Adsense (root)
    | //use: google-api-php-client-[RELEASE_NAME].zip
    | API -> src
          -> Vendor
    | // use: composer require google/apiclient:"^2.7"
    | Vendor
```

He probado en línea el uso de datos en:

- https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/get

Agregando mi id publicitario: `pub-1131234354566` pero a la hora de querer visualizar datos por método `HTPP`:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/pub-1131234354566/adclients?key=AIzaAsDfGuYn6nk9761kvnwMxns-PPeO1Ka1YsA
```

Me genera el siguiente error, cabe recalcar que estos errores no sucede al probar en línea:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Ya he creado las credenciales `API`, y `OAUTH2`

```
API_KEY: AIzaAsDfGuYn6nk9761kvnwMxns-PPeO1Ka1YsA
CLIENT_ID: 15123456862-94jrd0d2lis29lbl6dekpk0fp4otgm8r.apps.googleusercontent.com
CLIENT_SECRET: qertf3l3UfgdhjiWEREZI8xN
```

He consultado varios ejemplos:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873774/can-not-access-the-adsense-management-api
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280836/access-to-data-using-google-adsense-management-api-php

Plantillas de google adsense:

- https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AdSense%20Management%20API/v1.4

¿Han usado la API de Google Adsense?

¿Cómo debo crear mi estructura básica PHP, validando autorizando con mis credenciales y así poder imprimir datos de mi cuenta, datos como el rpm de impresión, pagos, ganancias del día u otro tipo de información de manera correcta?